# How to properly use class methods in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on this:

```
//
// Application: Golf App Server
// Author: Andres Martinez
// Year: 2016
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package com.andress.golfappserver.listener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import com.andress.golfappserver.beans.Client;
import com.andress.golfappserver.client.ClientHandler;
import com.andress.golfappserver.client.ClientStatus;

/**
 * This class has two main goals. First, start to listening the server in a certain port and
 * second, accepting incoming connections from clients. It runs as a Thread. The server
 * Administrator should provide the number of the port. When the Listener object is initialized
 * the ServerSocket will be listening to the port provided. To start to accept new connections
 * the Thread should be started. The Listener will create a new Client object every time when accepts
 * a new connection. The new Client will have the Socket accepted and a ClientStatus by default of
 * Connected. Then, a ClientHandler will be created with the Client as an argument.
 * The ClientController will be notified every time a new ClientHandler Thread is created.
 */
public class Listener implements Runnable {
  private final int port;
  private final ServerSocket serverSocket;

  /**
   * The Listener is instantiated and initialized with a port number
   * supplied by the Server Administrator. Then, the constructor
   * creates a new SeverSocket with this port ready to start to listen
   * for new connections.
   * @param port  Integer to identify port.
   */
  public Listener(final int port) {
    this.port = port;
    this.serverSocket = listen();
  }

  public int getPort() {
    return port;
  }

  public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
    return serverSocket;
  }

  /**
   * Creates Client objects for accepted connections and spawns
   * a new ClientHandler for each of the new Client connections.
   */
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Client client = createClient(accept(this.serverSocket));
    ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(client);
    //clientHandler.start();
  }

  /**
   * Binds the port provided by the Server Administrator to a new
   * ServerSocket.
   * @return  ServerSocket listening to the port provided.
   */
  private final ServerSocket listen() {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
      return serverSocket;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Starts to listen for connections to the port specified.
   * @param serverSocket  ServerSocket to listen for.
   * @return  Socket of the accepted connection.
   */
  private final Socket accept(final ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    try (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) {
      return clientSocket;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Client Bean with ClientStatus by default
   * of Connected and the Socket of the new connection.
   * @param clientSocket  Socket for the new connection.
   * @return  Client object with ClientStatus of Connected by default.
   */
  private final Client createClient(final Socket clientSocket) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setSocket(clientSocket);
    client.setStatus(ClientStatus.CONNECTED);
    return client;
  }
}
```

I'm having an error with the socket but, I'm not interested in this particular error. What I would like to know if a thread always need the code to be executed inside the run() method or is there a way to do it like I'm attempting to do it?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at com.andress.golfappserver.listener.Listener.accept(Listener.java:85)
    at com.andress.golfappserver.listener.Listener.run(Listener.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:509)
    at com.andress.golfappserver.listener.Listener.accept(Listener.java:82)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: For creating a server listening/waiting for clients, this is the classic and proven way of doing. For other utilities that can be used in multi-threaded environments have look into java.util.concurrent package. Or if you want to explore more see akka framework.

Comment: Well, due to is my first attempt with multithreading and the app I'm coding is pretty simple I would like to keep it as simple as possible. :)

Comment: you might be interested in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html

Comment: @techtrainer Thanks for the link. I'm going to check it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a thread always need the code to be executed inside the `run()` method

Yes. That's what a Java `Thread` does.

> or is there a way to do it like I'm attempting to do it?

You're actually calling some methods inside `run()`, so it should work altogether.

#### UPDATE

In `accept()` method:

```java
private final Socket accept(final ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    try (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) {
        return clientSocket;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

You are accepting the socket in a [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construction. It means that as soon as this method ends, the socket closes. I bet that's not what you want to be done. Try this instead:

```java
private final Socket accept(final ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    try {
        return serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what I'm trying to do should work as well, right? If I declare methods in my class and I call them from the run() method, they should work just as well as if they were declared inside the run() method directly?

Comment: @lbpeppers yes, Java allows it

Comment: Let me show you the error I'm getting and could you help me to check what is my mistake?

Comment: @lbpeppers the socket error, right? i suggest you to should open another question, or else this one would be messed up. Ping me back here later

Comment: I already edited the post. If you see the error is with the accept() method. The socket isn't opened to accept connections inside the thread.

Comment: Yes, could be that. I'm going to check.

Comment: Yes, that was, I was closing the sockets so was impossible to use them in the run() method. Thank you @nandsito

Comment: @lbpeppers no prob. I had removed the `final` method modifier for no reason, so feel free to put it back if you wish

Comment: No worries, I changed directly from my original code. :)